# Adding pointer addresses - legality

Tags: c, pointers

Since adding two pointers together is illegal, how is this code snippet valid?

```
struct key *low = &tab[0]; 
struct key *high = &tab[n]; 
struct key *mid; 

while (low < high) 
{ 
  mid = low + (high-low) / 2; //isn't this adding pointers?


//code continues...
```

The first statement in the while loop seems to add two addresses together, how is this legal?

This code is from K&Rs the C programming language on page 122

Comment: "Since `X` is illegal, why is `Y` valid." ???

Comment: @EdHeal: no: (a) it's adding an *integer* to a pointer, which is legal and (b) it's not legal to *add* two pointers. *Subtracting* two pointers is perfectly legal.

Comment: @KerrekSB no, it's not adding pointers. It adds an integer to a pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB I wasn't aware of high - low giving an integer result so the code snippet made it appear that two pointers were being added and hence the opening sentence.

Comment: Debugger. Use one. :-D

Comment: Remember: pointers are like dates: `1jan2001 + 2feb2002 == 3mar4003` makes no sense. `2feb2002 - 1jan2001 == '1day+1 month+1 year` makes perfect sense (or : `397 days`). `1jan2001 + 397days` would make sense as well.

Comment: What exactly did you think `high - low` was?! (It's always good to remain critical and question one's every belief...)

Comment: @joop: +1, nice analogy.

Comment: @KerrekSB I thought high - low would give an address.

Comment: @joop I like that analogy, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *difference* of two pointers (`high - low`) is an *integer* (actually `ptrdiff_t`, which is a signed integer type), so you're adding an *integer* to a pointer, which is perfectly legal. This also explains why it's perfectly OK to divide the difference by 2, which is not something you could do with a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to subtract two pointers(*the result is [ptrdiff_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t)*) and you are allowed to add an integer value to a pointer. This is covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.6` *Additive operators* paragrph *2*:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)

and paragraph *3*:

> For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:

and includes the following bullets:

> both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible object
>   types; or

Some important notes, when subtracting two pointers they must point to the same array, this is covered in paragraph *9* which says:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; [...]

In order to avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) the resulting pointer from an addition must still point to the same array or one off the end of the array and if you point to one past the end you shall not dereference it, which is in paragraph *8* which says:

> [...]If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The difference of two pointers `high - low` is a value with an arithmetic, integral type (representable by a value of type `ptrdiff_t`, in case you need to store it). It's perfectly allowed to add integral values to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're subtracting two pointers that point to elements of the same array, or just past the last element of the same array, then the subtraction is the difference (in array elements) between them. The return value is a signed integer type, ptrdiff_t which is from stddef.h.

So, `high - low` is returning this signed integer which is then being added to low. So you're not adding pointers, you're adding a pointer with a signed integer type.

Comment: Wow, just int he time I was typing this in a bunch of people answered faster than me. :)